# SQL query using CONTAINS doesn't work on specify keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I am writing a simple query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE CONTAINS(Column1, 'MY')
```

but it doesn't return any results. While using `like` it returns results.

Is there any specific reason why the keyword 'MY' doesn't work?

Update:
If I use other keywords, it works, only the specific 'MY' seems to be that I cannot used. My column is already set into fulltext index. Also for performance purposes I prefer to use CONTAINS.

Comment: from the  spec: "CONTAINS is a predicate used in the WHERE clause of a Transact-SQL SELECT statement to perform SQL Server full-text search *on full-text indexed columns* containing character-based data types." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
select * from Table1 where Column1 like '%MY%'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use linq you can use the statements like you use in C#. It will be translated to SQL, a language which database can execute. So, try something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 like @Column1";
```

And in your command, try to add parameters to replace the `@Column1`

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", "%MY%");
```

The `%` char, represents anything. So, if you want to do a command like `StartWith` like we do from string, just use `MY%`.